# Invalid Stream header Error in WEKA - CSV Loading

Tags: csv, weka

Invalid Stream header Error in WEKA - CSV Loading

Unable to load simple CSV file in weka

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it looks like you clicked on **Open...** in the GenericObjectEditor window instead of **OK** to accept the configuration of the `CSVLoader` class to load your CSV dataset.

The **Open...** and **Save...** buttons are for loading/saving **object templates**, not for loading/saving the CSV file (you are in the process of loading a CSV file, so a *Save* button makes no sense for this operation).

With this template functionality, you can maintain a library of commonly used setups for any Weka object (loader, saver, filter, classifier, etc.) and simply load it back into the GenericObjectEditor when you need it.

[image: CSVLoader in GenericObjectEditor]

Answer (score 0):

In the Experimenter->Datasets-> Use relative path (check this box)